# Destructuring the return of a function that may return undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code;

**App.tsx**

```
  const handleKeyDown = ({key}: {key: string}) => {

    const [newDirection, nextWalkingState, newPosition] = handleDogMovement(key, dogObject, invalidPositionsTest);
  }

export const handleDogMovement = (key: string, dogObject : Tile, invalidPositions : Position[]) => {
  const newDirection = mapKeyDownToDirectionImpl[key.toLowerCase()];
  if (!newDirection) return;

  const {direction, walkingState, pos} = dogObject;
  const nextWalkingState = newDirection === direction ? walkingState! + 2 : 2;
  const {offsetX, offsetY} = mapDirectionToOffset[newDirection];
  const newPosition = {x: pos.x + offsetX, y: pos.y + offsetY}
  if (!isNewPositionValid(newPosition, invalidPositions)) return;
  return [newDirection, nextWalkingState, newPosition];
}
```

However, it's possible that handleDogMovement could return undefined. Can I still destructure the result this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't; it'd throw an error.  Try this:

```js
const [newDirection, nextWalkingState, newPosition] = handleDogMovement(key, dogObject, invalidPositionsTest) || [];
```

Now your variables will be `undefined` if the function returns `undefined`, but at least you won't crash your script.